# Is there a simple way to find out the last line executed in a bash script?

Tags: shell-script, debugging

I'm running a bash script which contains a for loop which will run thousands of times. Somewhere in this for loop the code often gets stuck (lowest number of iterations I have seen it stop on is 32, most it has stopped on is in the high 4000s - it is supposed to run 5000 times, sometimes it completes the task). I would like to debug this problem. Obviously, I don't want to manually enters hundreds of thousands of lines of code into the command window and wait for the one where it will get stuck.

Is there a simple way to find out what the last line it executed or tried to execute was? (Bearing in mind that when it goes wrong the terminal appears to be frozen - sometimes the entire system stops working and requires an off-at-the-wall reset to get it started again.) I thought this might be a feature of echo. I found [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109225/bash-echoing-the-last-command-run) but I am not sure what "when commands represent a specific line in my script from a parser standpoint" means and therefore if it is applicable. I'm also pretty confused by what this code actually does and would appreciate for dummies explanation if this code will help me.

Is this the answer I am looking for? Is there another solution to this problem?

Comment: This is what debuggers are useful for. Searching for 'bash debuggers' should net you a lot of results. A bit of warning, debuggers can be complicated, but there are lots of resources for learning. In this case, I do not think using the `echo` command will benefit you in any way inside the for-loop.

Comment: Good to know, I'll stop looking into echo-related material.

Comment: Not that there is anything wrong with echo, you will probably use it often. I would just recommend caution when running additional commands inside of a loop with that many iterations, especially if it is already crashing sporadically. A small script can very quickly become resource intensive. Just ask the fork bomb.

Comment: Does the script process 1 iteration successfully?

Comment: @eyoung100 Yes, it runs many times, sometimes it even completes.

Comment: What are you processing?

Comment: I'm calling and running a model with variables that I set in the bash script. It's a monte carlo simulation.

Comment: The card game, or the car?

Comment: It's a monte carlo simulation as in the modelling method used for all manner of scientific purposes where you have a large number of variables. You randomly assign values within set bounds and look at the outputs. In my case it is a cloud model.

Comment: OK, use the method in the answer below to count the number of iterations.  Put it all in a Do until, and set the Do until to 500, run, then 1000, then run, then 2000.  It may not be the logic but the number of iterations... if its not the number the data you're receiving is "dirty."

Comment: You could also use `set +x` to show exactly what command is being parsed, command by command.

Answer (score 3):

First you should try to determine in which iteration the problem occurs. If you are lucky then it is always the same. If you do not do that anyway then you should count the iterations and print them or write them to a file:

```
exec 3>/my/logfile
iter=0
while whatevercondition; do
  ((iter++))
  echo "$iter" >&3
done
```

If the problem occurs always in the same iteration then you should activate debug output then:

```
CRASH_ITER=12345
iter=0
while whatevercondition; do
  ((iter++))
  if [ "$iter" -eq "$CRASH_ITER" ]; then
    set -vx
  fi
done
```

**non-reproducible errors**

If it is not possible to narrow the error to a certain iteration then you can have bash write the complete debug output to a file:

```
bash -vx ./script.sh 2>debug.txt
```

Comment: Unfortunately the iteration the error occurs on is not always the same It is not always the same seen numbers anywhere between 32 and 4885 out of 5000 iterations. Sometimes the code even completes!

Comment: @Reluctant_Linux_User I extended my answer accordingly.

Comment: I take it that I am using that as a command to start the bash script - yes?

Comment: @Reluctant_Linux_User Yes. It has the same effect like `set -vx` within a script but is usually easier to change.

Comment: OK, well the code just crashed in fact it's crashed the entire system (writing this on a stable system) so I guess I can give that a go.

Comment: @Reluctant_Linux_User If the whole system crashes then the relevant information may not have made it into the logfile. But usually shell scripts don't crash the system. I guess that didn't happen before as you didn't mention it. It would be interesting, though, if the `bash -vx` caused the more severe result of the crash. You will find out...

Comment: I'm not that good at this game: I'm going to edit my question to include further relevant information. Today (though not previously) I have experienced several complete crashes of the system when trying to run this code. I have run it many times previously without this problem happening. However, perhaps the two are linked?

Comment: @Reluctant_Linux_User You should really post the code you want debugged.  Asking people to hypothesize about about something that could really be doing anything is a tad ridiculous; with regard to your general question, Hauke's suggestion of using `-vx` is the general answer.

Comment: This code involves running a gigantic model. I reckon I'd hit allowable length limit before I could post it and even then someone owns parts of the code which I'm pretty sure I'm not supposed to make public. I could post (one of the versions of) the bash script that calls it? Would that be acceptable?

Comment: Using this causes crashes almost instantly. I'm still investigating how to get it to run reliably.

Comment: If it's too long, etc., yeah, you have to solve this yourself.  It is not that unusual to spend more time debugging a piece of "completed" code than it took to write it.  Because of the nature of the beast, good programming tends to focus on writing code that makes debugging easier, as opposed to coming up with ways to debug anything later regardless of how it was written.  Maybe you have to go through this line by line, commenting things out and shimming things in to balance out, etc.

Comment: ...If you really have a gigantic loop of **[spaghetti](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghetti_code)**, don't forget the lesson, and *don't believe it had to be this way*.  If what you are doing requires you keep writing code, it might be worthwhile to learn some better general methodology and save hours ad infinitum of grief in the future.  If you aren't responsible for this, find the person that is, chloroform them, and leave them gagged and bound in the woods somewhere ;)

Answer (score 2):

If you add this to the top of your bash script:

```
   function DEBUG_TRAP() { 
      typeset -p BASH_SOURCE; typeset -p BASH_LINENO; typeset -p FUNCNAME
   }
   trap DEBUG_TRAP INT
```

you may be able to get information about where the program is by sending the process the an INT signal:

`kill -INT process-number`

You can get the process number inside the bash script like this:

```
   echo $$
```

If you aren't getting any output after doing this then either your script has redirected its output, or the script is hung inside a process. lsof will tell you information about output redirection while *ps* will give information on the process status.

Answer (score 0):

If your loop looked like:

```
i=0
while [ "$((i+=1))" -le 5000 ] &&
      set >iter.log
do    monte_carlo
done
```

You'd get a file overwritten for each iteration which would list the current values of all shell variables each time. So if it breaks on run 488 you'd have have an *iter.log* file which recorded `$i`'s value as 488 and all of the other shell variables at the beginning of the iteration.

To track the failing line number you can go a little further:

```
i=0 PS4='$LINENO : '; set -x
while [ ... ] &&
      set >iter.log
do    ...
done 2>>iter.log
```

That would still overwrite the file for every iteration, but it would also append debug output for every line executed and include its line number in the file.